# Finding the highest divisible sum of elements in an array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I need to find the highest possible sum of numbers in an array passed to a function that can be divided with no remainder.

I am struggling to think of a way of iterating through an array of elements adding up all the possibilities and dividing by the parameter `k` which is the number for the division.

I thought of using a for loop and then passing the result to a variable on each iteration.

The part I can't get my head around is how to add all the possible combinations of the numbers in the array. As I can add them sequentially from the start of the array to the last element but not in all combinations such as element at index `0`, element at index `3` etc.

I am fairly new to coding, explanations of how you could tackle the iteration challenge I have would be much appreciated.

```
function luckyCandies(prizes, k) {
  let sum = 0;
  let remainder = 0;
  let maxCandies = 0;
  let highestNumber = 0;

  prizes.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b - a;
  });

  for (let i = 0; i < prizes.length; i++) {
    sum = sum + prizes[i];
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < prizes.length; i++) {
    if (sum % k == 0) {
      sum = sum - prizes[i];
    }
  }

  console.log(sum);

  return sum;
}
```

Comment: Please format your question so that it is not a wall of text. And only include what is necessary for your problem. There is no need to say that you are new to programming or if that topic might be useful for real-life problems. That adds just noise for the one trying to figure out what the actual problem is and does not bring any additional insights to the case.

Comment: `The part I can't get my head around is how to add all the possible combinations of the numbers in the array.` Showing what output you expect for a given example input would help much.

Comment: Thank you no problem I will keep it succinct in future kind regards Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implemented this solution for your use case based on the answers in [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/greatest-sum-divisible-by-three/discuss/439097/Javascript-and-C%2B%2B-solutions).

In the given link the solutions are for the **highest possible sum of numbers given the divisible `3`** but it won't be a problem since there is a proper in detailed explanation.

```js
const maxSumDivByNo = (A, no) => {
    const K = Array(no).fill().map((v,i) => 0);
    for (let x of A) {
        let pre = [...K]; // create current from previous 
        for (let y of pre)
            K[(x + y) % no] = Math.max(K[(x + y) % no], x + y); // add A[i] (ie. x) onto each previous bucket and update each current bucket to max of itself and the current sum (x + y)
    }
    return K[0]; // max sum of all N items of A which is evenly divisible by no 
};

const A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const no = 5;
console.log(maxSumDivByNo(A, no)); // --> 15

const A1 = [1, 6, 2, 9, 5];
const no1 = 8
console.log(maxSumDivByNo(A1, no1)); // --> 16
```